# determine the periodic loan payment

Tags: java

am not getting this program to display my instalments correctly can I please get some help thanks......

```
package Loops;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //variabled decleared
        double rate;
        double payment;
        //input
        System.out.print("Enter Loan Amount:");
        double principal = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter Annual Interest:");
        double interest = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Total payments per year:");//12=monthly,4= quartely,2=semi-annually and 1=annually
        double period = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter Loan Length :");
        int length = input.nextInt();

        //proces
        double n = period * length;
        rate = interest / 100;
        double monthly_rate = rate / period;
        payment = principal * (principal * (monthly_rate * Math.pow((1 + monthly_rate), n)));

        System.out.printf("Your Monthly sum is %.2f", payment);


    }
}
```

Comment: What you are expecting and what you got?

Comment: not an answer but just follow java naming conventions. package names should start with lowercase and class names should start with upper case.

Comment: am getting 375 but it suppose to be 750 since I input 500dollars and 50% interest for 1 year....

Comment: example on what am suppose to do please tell me if am going wrongAs an example, a business might borrow from a bank a sum of $8500 to be re-paid quarterly at an annual rate of 8.5% over a period of 4 years. In this example: 
•  The principal = $50,000 
•  The annual rate of interest = 8.5% 
•  The re-payment period is quarterly 
•  The length of time of the loan = 4 years 
Your first job in the program is to determine the periodic payment. This is done using the 
formula: 

Payment =Principal *  
NOTE:  You can use r* Math.pow ((1+r),n)   to calculate the numerator and part of the denominator

Comment: You're missing a bunch of terms from your formula and multiplying where you should be dividing.  Google turned up [this page](http://www.1728.org/loanform.htm) as the first hit for 'monthly payment formula'.  Your formula as written here yields a 5 digit number, not 375, so some of this may be transcription errors with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your formula:

```
//this is how much a monthly payment is
payment = (rate + (rate / ((Math.pow(1 + rate), n) -1)) * principal
```

This is based off one of the first google results for the formula. Please post the results and expected answer if it is wrong.

I'm pretty sure your formula is just off, as you stated above that there should be a denominator in the equation.

`You can use r* Math.pow ((1+r),n) to calculate the numerator and part of the denominator`

Answer (score 1):

```
principal = 50000; //Redacted. Eating my words.

period = 4;
length = 4;
n = 16;

rate = 0.085;
monthly_rate = 0.085 / 16 = 0.0053125;

payment = 50000 * 50000 * 0.0053125 * (1 + 0.0053125) ^ 16;
        = 2.5x10^9 * 0.0053125 * 1.088;
        = Something remainingly massive
```

Basically... your formula is wrong. Wouldn't you need to *divide* by the power quotient? Where is your source on that formula?

```
payment = principal * (rate + (rate / ( Math.pow(1 + rate, n) - 1) ) );
```

[Source](http://www.1728.org/loanform.htm)

Example:

```
payment = 50000*(0.085+(0.085/(1.085^16-1)))
= 5830.68
```

Comment: payment = principal * principal*(monthly_rate*(1+monthly_rate)^n); am getting an error saying bad operand type for binary operator

Comment: Note that `^` in java is bitwise exclusive OR. You should use Math.pow().

Comment: actually his spelling is ok. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_sum#principal_sum

Comment: Apologies Shawn. I was just using the code block in my answer to show the math without formatting taking over. If you're looking to do the correct formula I edited one into my answer.

Comment: Thanks alot this formula works great payment = principal * (rate + (rate / ( Math.pow(1 + rate, n) - 1) ) );